# Почему в "пух и прах"?

Tags: фразеология

"Разбить в пух и прах" говорят о чем-то, что разгромлено на голову. Но почему именно пух и почему именно прах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Первоначально слова пух и прах были
> связаны с глаголами, обозначавшими
> конкретные действия: с
> *пуш**и**/ть/распуш**и**/ть* "взбивать/взбить
> или, взбивая, расчёсывать/расчесать
> лежалую, свалявшуюся шерсть, волосы и
> т. п." (букв. "делать/сделать пухлым,
> как пух"), а также с архаизмами
> *праш**и**/ть/распраш**и**/ть,
> порош**и**/ть/распорош**и**/ть*
> "дробить/раздробить на мелкие
> частички, превращать/превратить в
> прах, в пыль". Самостоятельно
> употреблялись и выражения *разбить в
> пух* "взбивая, распушить", *разбить в
> прах* "раздробить в порошок, измельчить
> в пыль, ударяя". Отсюда переносные
> значения "разгромить" и "сильно
> отругать" (ср. *распушить*
> "разбранить"). В дальнейшем в связи со
> сходством значений произошло слияние
> двух оборотов в один, расширение
> значения и сочетаемости (см.
> *разориться, проиграться, разругаться в
> пух и прах*).

Мелерович А.М., Мокиенко В.М. Фразеологизмы в русской речи.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется выражение самодостаточно. Прах - останки, мельчайшие частицы, пыль. так что тут понятно. 
А на пух - это видимо в том же значении, что и в выражении "пух и перья" летят. Последнее бывает при неаккуратном ощипывании птицы, но чаще всего - года лиса или хорек заберется в курятник.